# Returning a Json Object won't work, only returning a string will

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to return a list of json objects to the view, however it's not liking that its an object, it will work if i return a string or a list of strings. But really I don't need the whole object in the view, I really just need the name and the Id. How can i change this to return a list of the names and matching Id to the View and then insert/update all the names into a listbox? Any help is appreciated. :)

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetUserStories(int id)
    {
        var userstorylist = userRepository.Select().Where(x => x.EpicId.Equals(id)).ToList();
        var userstorynames = userstorylist.Select(x => x.Name);

        return Json(userstorynames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View:

```
          $.getJSON("/Estimate/GetUserStories", $.param({ id: selectedid }, true), function (result) {
            $(".UserStoryListBoxClass").html("");
            for (var item in result) {
                $(".UserStoryListBoxClass").append($("<option>" + result[item] + "</option>"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `json` result is something like this

```
[{"Id": "1","Name": "Skeet"},{"Id": "2","Name": "Darin"}]
```

The below code will work,

```
 $.getJSON("/Estimate/GetUserStories", $.param({ id: selectedid }, true), function (result) {
    var items="";
    $.each(result, function(index) {
       items+="<option value="+result[index].Id+">" + result[index].Name+ "</option>";
    });
    $(".UserStoryListBoxClass").html(items);    
 });
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/CFdeW/14/

**Never do the `append` method in the loop for adding elements to a drop down**. Always store it into a variable and call the html method **only once**.

Comment: Where does jsonData in the $.each come from? Thanks for response :)

Comment: @TMan: That is same as of result. I used JsonData in example.  updated my example now.

Answer (score 2):

To return tuples with id and name you can do:

```
var userstorynames = userstorylist.Select(x => new { id = x.Id, name = x.Name }).ToList();
```